# object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi I keep getting this error and I don't know how to circumvent this.

I have the following code:

```
class retrieve_account_data(Thread):
    _account_queue = None
    _dict_of_db_logging_objects = {}

    def __init__(self,name):
        super(retrieve_account_data,self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def set_account_queue(self,account):
        self._account_queue = account

    def set_db_logging_object(self,db_logging_object):
        self._db_logging_object = db_logging_object

    def run(self):
        latest_account_object = self._account_queue.get(block = True)
        latest_account_object.get_account_balances()
        old_account_object = copy.deepcopy(latest_account_object)
        self._account_queue.put(copy.deepcopy(old_account_object))

        while True:
            latest_account_object.get_account_balances()
            if ((old_account_object.get_base_currency_amount() !=
                 latest_account_object.get_base_currency_amount()) or
                (old_account_object.get_quote_currency_amount() !=
                 latest_account_object.get_quote_currency_amount())):

                old_account_object = copy.deepcopy(latest_account_object)
                self._account_queue.put(copy.deepcopy(old_account_object))

                if (old_account_object.get_name_of_exchange() not in
                    self._dict_of_db_logging_objects):
                    self._dict_of_db_logging_objects[
                                old_account_object.get_name_of_exchange()] =
                                (db_logging("account_balances",
                                 old_account_object.get_name_of_exchange()))

                self._dict_of_db_logging_objects.log_account_data_to_db(
                            old_account_object.get_base_currency_amount(),
                            old_account_object.get_quote_currency_amount(),
                            time.time())
```

The thread is started like this in main

```
account_queue = Queue.Queue()
retrieve_account_data = retrieve_account_data("trade_account")
retrieve_account_data.set_account_queue(account_queue)
account_queue.put(account)
retrieve_account_data.start()
```

There is a second thread that receives the accounts on the other side of the queue. `account` is a object that contains several other objects. `get_balances()` does an http request to get some json data.
What I want to do is minimize communication between the `retrieve_account_data` thread and the consuming thread. That is why I'm storing the old version of account and comparing to the new version of account.

The other side has a similar mechanism when new account data is available, it stores the account object or if there is no new data it will use the last account data.

So how can I solve this without getting an error?

@martineau here is the error reported by eclipse sorry for the bad formatting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner  
  self.run()  
  File "/Users/angus/fortunate_one/fortunate_one/src/thread_handling/process_orders.py", line 133, in run  
    old_account_object = copy.deepcopy(latest_account_object)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy  
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct  
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy  
    y = copier(x, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict  
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy  
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct  
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy  
    y = copier(x, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict  
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy  
    y = copier(x, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 298, in _deepcopy_inst  
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy  
    y = copier(x, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict  
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy  
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct  
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy  
    y = copier(x, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict  
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy  
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct  
    y = callable(*args)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__  
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)  
TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? If there's a stacktrace, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since I only needed very few data of the object I create a new one every time I get changed Account data. I deepcopy this keep the original in the thread and put the copy in the queue, which seemed to work so far.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `deepcopy` (it is almost always certainly wrong). `deepcopy` will copy all referred to objects; in this case your object graph has some locks; they are not copiable by `deepcopy` and thus you get the error.

Comment: But what is the best way to duplicate data in an other way?

Comment: Best I do not know, I'd have to know more about the code, but I'd say "anything else than `deepcopy`"

Comment: @daeda: In this case you should just create a custom copy routine to copy over the attributes you need.