# Why does running `airflow clear` using the -t option raise a thread error?

Tags: python, airflow

I've constructed an Airflow DAG with default settings as the tutorial. When I run the DAG, some tasks failed. When I attempt to clear the failed tasks using `airflow clear my_dag -s 2016-08-03 -t my_task_name -fd`, I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()
```

Is this an issue with Airflow itself, or is it something on my side?

The full backtrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 379, in clear
    include_upstream=args.upstream,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2870, in sub_dag
    dag = copy.deepcopy(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2856, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1974, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2856, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1974, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()
```

Comment: learn how to ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks Youcef, updated to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use deepcopy (it is almost always certainly wrong). deepcopy will copy all referred to objects; in this case your object graph has some locks; they are not copiable by deepcopy and thus you get the error.

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267261/object-new-thread-lock-is-not-safe-use-thread-lock-new)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue for Airflow: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-351

Answer (score 0):

Can you share you my_dag code? If you are passing complex object to your operator, you will run into issue with deepcopy.

See this one example below. Here the parameter for config_file is a file and it is complex type and in this case, there will be deepcopy issue. Instead of passing this parameter, you can pass all parameters as individual attributes. Or you can have this property file variable set in the operator itself instead of passing as parameter.

```
job_flow = MySpecialOperator(
    task_id='create_ec2instance',
    aws_conn_id='service_aws',
    config_file='dev_ec2instance_parameters.cfg',
    initializer_task_id='initializer',
    dag=dag
)
```